# How to to print nested [object Object] without affecting other types

Tags: javascript, string, stringify

I am currently trying to show some data on my webpage (not the console, actually inject it into a paragraph) which (for example) looks as follows:

```
["accept", "#PID<0.395.0>", {"id": "N1", "num": 1}, "Appeltaart"]
```

The way I would like to print this is:

```
[accept, #PID<0.395.0>, {id: N1, num: 1}, Appeltaart]
```

However, the way I get it printed now when I do no pre-processing is:

```
accept, #PID<0.395.0>,[object Object], Appeltaart
```

Note that my nested `Objects` now are not converted to a string and my original list also disappeared. When I print it using the `JSON.stringify()` beforehand, I get the following:

```
["accept", "#PID<0.395.0>", {"id": "N1", "num": 1}, "Appeltaart"]
```

Note that around every value there are now quote (`"`) symbols. How would I achieve the result I desire?

Comment: Stringify and then [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) the quotes with `''`?

Comment: Why do you desire that specific result? Doesn't seem any more useful than just JSON-encoding the entire thing…?

Comment: The quotes make everything much less readable and it's unnecessary anyway.

Comment: @Andy That worked! There might be a more efficient solution, but this works wonders for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom object printer like this:

```js
function printObj(v) {
  if(typeof v === 'object') {
    return Array.isArray(v) ? 
      `[${v.map(i=>typeof i==='object' ? printObj(i) : i).join(', ')}]` : 
      `{${Object.entries(v).map(([k,v])=>`${k}: ${v}`).join(', ')}}`
  }
  else return v
}

const arr = ["accept", "#PID<0.395.0>", {"id": "N1", "num": 1}, "Appeltaart"]

console.log(printObj(arr))
```